# How to add OR to the test of an IF THEN conditional in BASH?

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

I have a conditional like this:

```
if [ "$day" == "1" ]
then
    echo "First day."
fi
```

I want to add an additional conditional, so that if either are true, it will print "First day", e.g.:

```
IF $day IS 1 OR $a IS 1
THEN
    "First day."
FI
```

How can this be done in BASH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if [ "$day" == "1" ] ||  [ "$a" == "1" ]; then     echo "First day."; fi`

or

```
if [ "$day" == "1" ] || [ “$a" == "1" ]
then
    echo "First day."
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Keeping POSIX compatibility, there are two options:

```
if [ "$day" = "1" ] || [ "$a" = "1" ]; then ... fi

if [ "$day" = "1" -o "$a" = "1" ]; then ... fi
```

In bash, there are two additional options:

```
if [[ $day = 1 || $a = 1 ]]; then ... fi

if (( day == 1 || a == 1 )); then ... fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`-o`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) (logical or):

```
if [ "$day" == "1" -o "$a" == "1" ]
then
    echo "First day."
fi
```